# Problem when adding dependencies to build.sbt

Tags: scala, javafx, import, dependencies, sbt

I have the following snippet of code in my `build.sbt` file for a Scala project:

```
// for scalaFX
libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "16.0.0-R24",
scalacOptions       += "-Ymacro-annotations",

// for scalaFXML
libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx" %% "scalafxml-core-sfx8" % "0.5",

// for terminalFX
libraryDependencies += "com.kodedu.terminalfx" % "terminalfx" % "1.2.0",

resolvers           += "terminalfx-repo" at "https://github.com/javaterminal/TerminalFX/blob/master/releases",
```

However, I faced this error:

```
not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/kodedu/terminalfx/terminalfx/1.2.0/terminalfx-1.2.0.pom
```

Would anyone know why it attempted to search for the `.pom` file in this path and not the one specified in the resolver? Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because a rendered preview of a file in a master branch on a GitHub is not a Maven artifact. It renders a HTML page, and resolver expects XML.

You added

```
https://github.com/javaterminal/TerminalFX/blob/master/releases
```

while [the documentations](https://github.com/javaterminal/TerminalFX#5-maven-dependency) suggests

```
https://github.com/javaterminal/terminalfx/raw/master/releases
```

This `raw` instead of `blob` is a huge difference.