# Compilation errors with Scala imports

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following code in my `build.sbt` file for a Scala project:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.kodedu.terminalfx" % "terminalfx-repo" % "1.2.0" from "https://github.com/javaterminal/TerminalFX/raw/master/releases"
```

However, in another file when I try to import as such:

```
import com.kodedu.terminalfx.TerminalBuilder
```

I face the following errors:

```
object kodedu is not a member of package com
```

Would anyone know how this compilation error was caused? Any help would be greatly appreciated! [docs](https://github.com/javaterminal/TerminalFX#5-maven-dependency)

Comment: Previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75701487/problem-when-adding-dependencies-to-build-sbt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to specify `resolvers`. And `artifactId` is `terminalfx` instead of `terminalfx-repo`.

```
resolvers += "terminalfx-repo" at "https://github.com/javaterminal/terminalfx/raw/master/releases"
resolvers += Resolver.jcenterRepo // for the dependency: "org.jetbrains.pty4j" % "purejavacomm" % "0.0.11.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.kodedu.terminalfx" % "terminalfx" % "1.2.0"
```

Tested in Scala 2.13.10 + **Java 17**.

After sbt found `terminalfx` it still couldn't find the dependency `"org.jetbrains.pty4j" % "purejavacomm" % "0.0.11.1"`. Mvnrepository [says](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.pty4j/purejavacomm/0.0.11.1) that it's published at JCenter, so I added this repo manually too.

According to [sbt docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Explicit+URL), `"..." % "..." % "..." from "..."` is for jars

> **Explicit URL**
>
> If your project requires a dependency that is not present in a repository, a direct URL to its jar can be specified as follows:
>
> ```
> libraryDependencies += "slinky" % "slinky" % "2.1" from "https://slinky2.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/2.1/slinky.jar"
> ```
>
> The URL is only used as a fallback if the dependency cannot be found through the configured repositories. Also, the explicit URL is not included in published metadata (that is, the pom or ivy.xml).

Direct link to the jar https://github.com/javaterminal/TerminalFX/blob/master/releases/com/kodedu/terminalfx/terminalfx/1.2.0/terminalfx-1.2.0.jar?raw=true is ending with `?raw=true` (otherwise it's a html page). Not sure whether this is working in sbt with `from` directly.